# How to make Drupal 6 search result URL use "-" instead of space?

Tags: search, uri, 6

Example of Drupal 6 search result URL is like this:

```
http://www.site.com/search/node/Search for something
```

How to make Drupal 6 search result URL use `-` instead of space? (below is an example):

```
http://www.site.com/search/node/Search-for-something
```

Comment: When someone makes a search query with a dash in it, how should it be represented in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the functions [custom_url_rewrite_inbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/custom_url_rewrite_inbound/6) and [custom_url_rewrite_outbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/custom_url_rewrite_outbound/6) in the settings.php.

`custom_url_rewrite_outbound()` would rewrite the URLs which are output from any module, and `custom_url_rewrite_inbound()` would rewrite the URL being requested to Drupal.

This is the example code used in the documentation of `custom_url_rewrite_outbound()`.

```
function custom_url_rewrite_outbound(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  global $user;

  // Change all 'node' to 'article'.
  if (preg_match('|^node(/.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
    $path = 'article' . $matches[1];
  }
  // Create a path called 'e' which lands the user on her profile edit page.
  if ($path == 'user/' . $user->uid . '/edit') {
    $path = 'e';
  }
}
```

In your case, the code could be something similar to the following one.

```
function custom_url_rewrite_outbound(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  if (preg_match('|^search(/[^/]+/(.+))|', $path, $matches)) {
    $path = 'search/' . $matches[1] . str_replace(' ', '-', $matches[2]);
  }
}
```

`custom_url_rewrite_inbound()` should do the exact opposite.
The code I wrote does not consider the case the `-` is included in the search string. The code should consider that case, for example adding another `-` where there is already one; when it does the opposite operation, the code should first replace a single `-` with a space, and then remove a `-` where there are more of those characters in row.

Answer (score -3):

If you have installed pathauto module then Check admin/build/path/settings this setting.

Comment: Not sure how this would change the search URLs.  Can you eloborate?